# Cannot seem to get jQuery UI autocomplete to work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I realise that this is a very generalised question, but I am at my wits' end trying to get jQuery autocomplete to work with my rails search. I am running on rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.8.7. I wonder if someone might be able to decipher my problem, my code is as follows...

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_self
//= require products

$(".search").autocomplete({
    source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
});
```

View:

```
<form action="<%= products_path %>" method="get" id="searchBox">
    <%= text_field_tag 'search', params[:search], :class => 'search', :placeholder => "What are you looking for?" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "button large" %>
</form>
```

HTML Output:

```
<form action="/products" method="get" id="searchBox">
    <input class="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" type="text" />
    <input class="button large" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**Solution**

I was able to get this to work by modifying my jQuery. Though I am still unsure why the initial code worked with my test app and not my production app.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.search').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.autocomplete({source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']});
  });
});
```

Comment: Why does this not work for you? Have you included jquery-ui.js? Any errors in the console? Posting the HTML output of your code would be more helpful.

Comment: Hi Rory, I have added the HTML output. There are no errors, it just does not work. I created a clean test app and was able to run autocomplete successfully. But using the same code does not seem to work on my production app. Is it possible that something else in the app is preventing this from working properly?

Comment: There must be a conflict with another JS file. Sometimes it can be the ordering, when your app is ran on the server it will load the jquery, jquery_ujs and then jquery-ui. Which I think you should try swapping around, and that should work